# How can I fit data with flat lines over a specific range in R?

Tags: r, data-fitting

I have been trying to fit some data with a change in the average y-values over a certain range of x values. I have been stuck on trying to get this to work for a little while now.

For example, given some controlled randomized data and a desired fit:

```
library(tidyverse)

Data <- data.frame(Time = c(1:100, 101:500, 501:1000), 
                   Value = c(runif(100, 0, 500), 
                             runif(400, 500, 1000), 
                             runif(500, 0, 100)),
                   Desired_fit = c(rep_len(250,100), 
                                   rep_len(750,400),
                                   rep_len(50,500)))

plot(Data$Time, Data$Value)
lines(Data$Time, Data$Desired_fit, col = "red")
```

I have tried to smooth, get a running average, and spline my data, but this produced a curve fit instead of the Desired_fit above. In essence, I am trying to fit a horizontal line across each inflection point in the data set.

The closest thing I have tried is by using the rollmean()from the zoo package:

```
library(zoo)

moving_average <- rollmean(Data$Value, 50, fill = NA)

plot(Data$Time, Data$Value)
lines(Data$time, moving_average, col = "red")
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know in advance where the inflection points are, or if you don't, do you have a rule you want to follow that will reliably signify an inflection point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the segment breakpoints using `dpseg`. Each row of `dp$segments` defines one segment with `start` and `end`
columns being indexes of start and end points of that segment and `x1` and `x2` columns being the corresponding times.  Finally plot the means of the data in each segment.

```
library(dpseg)

plot(Value ~ Time, Data)

dp <- with(Data, dpseg(x = Time, y = Value, jumps = TRUE))
segs <- dp$segments

xx <- with(segs, c(rbind(x1, x2)))
yy <- mapply(\(st,en) mean(Data$Value[st:en]), segs$start, segs$end) |> rep(each=2)
lines(xx, yy, col = "red", lwd = 3)
```

[image: screenshot]

Alternately replace everything from the `xx<-...` line onwards above with the following if the vertical line segments are not wanted.

```
nr <- nrow(segs)
for(i in 1:nr) with(segs[i, ],
  segments(x0 = x1, 
           y0 = mean(Data$Value[start:end]),
           x1 = x2, col = "red", lwd = 3))
```

[image: screenshot]

### Old

This did not work so well.

Calculate the breakpoints using `breakpoints` from strucchange and then plot.the data and the fitted values.

```
library(strucchange)
bp <- with(Data, breakpoints(Value ~ 1))
plot(Value ~ Time, Data)
lines(fitted(bp) ~ Time, Data, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

Since random numbers were used to generate the data in the question we used set.seed first to make it reproducible.

```
set.seed(123)
Data <- data.frame(Time = c(1:100, 101:500, 501:1000), 
                   Value = c(runif(100, 0, 500), 
                             runif(400, 500, 1000), 
                             runif(500, 0, 100)),
                   Desired_fit = c(rep_len(250,100), 
                                   rep_len(750,400),
                                   rep_len(50,500)))
```